# Is there any property of the set of nilpotent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, nilpotence

Let k be a field, $M_nk$ its matrix ring. We denote the set of nilpotent matrices by $N$. What properties can we know about $N$? Is there any analogy of "nilradical" in the matrix ring? Could you share any ideas on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous [nilradicals of rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilradical_of_a_ring), all of which are zero anyways in $M_n(k)$ since it is a simple ring.

The set of nilpotent elements in a noncommutative ring does not have many useful properties.  They are not even closed under addition or multiplication, as evidenced by:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

and $\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

The only properties I can come up with at all right now is that they are closed under scalar multiplication and exponentiation, both of which are pretty trivial.